# Functions don't operate correctly (AutoIt)

Tags: function, hex, type-conversion, ascii, autoit

So i am trying to make a function out of many functions (i believe it is called recursion, read a post about it earlier on this forum)

When i try to make a number of things into 1 big function so i can call upon it later it doesn't seem to be working but when i take away the "func _hello()" and the "endfunc" from the end, everything seems to be working fine. Can someone please explain this to me. I know the problem is occurring because of the the "Conversion" function but i can't seem to understand why this is happening. Please help, language used here is AutoIt

```
;;;****Program adds spaces *****
;;;***** the input variable here is $New*****
Global $final
Global $Hexadec
Func _hello()

$DataToBeDecrypted = "55fdaf fdafd"

$2space = $DataToBeDecrypted
$New = $2space

$AddingSpace = StringSplit($New, "")

$Final = ""

If Conversion($AddingSpace[0]) Then

For $Spacing = 1 to $AddingSpace[0] Step 2
    $Final = $Final & $AddingSpace[$Spacing] & $AddingSpace[$Spacing+1] & " "
Next

MsgBox(0, "Adding space to the message so it can be converted back to Hex",     $Final)

Else
MsgBox(0, "Result", "String does not contain an even number of characters.")
EndIf

Func Conversion($Hexadec)
Return Mod($Hexadec, 2) = 0
EndFunc
;;;***The final value is stored in the $final variable****


;***** Hexadecimals to ASCII***** 
;;***Input variable is $HexadecimaltoASCII2******

$HexadecimalToASCII2 =$final
$HexadecimalsToASCII = ChrH($HexadecimalToASCII2)
$Ascii2Hex = Sub($HexadecimalsToASCII)
$v5ar = Chr($HexadecimalsToASCII);char

MsgBox(0,"Hex to ASCII",$HexadecimalsToASCII)

Func ChrH($v8)

Local $v5=""
$A1 = StringSplit($v8, " ")
For $count = 1 To $A1[0]
    $v5 &= Chr(Dec($A1[$count]))
Next
Return $v5
endFunc


Func Sub($v8)

Local $v9=""
For $count = 1 To StringLen($v8)
    If StringLen(Hex(Asc(StringMid($v8, $count, 1)),2)) = 1 Then
        $v9 &=  "0" & Hex(Asc(StringMid($v8, $count, 1)))
    Else
        $v9 &=  Hex(Asc(StringMid($v8, $count, 1)),2)
    EndIf
    If $count <> StringLen($v8) Then $v9 &=  " "
Next
Return $v9
endFunc

 ;*****HEXADECIMAL to ASCII*****

EndFunc
```

Comment: Each `Func` needs a closing `EndFunc`. In your code it's seems as if the functions **Conversion**, **ChrH** and **Sub** are all within the function **_hello**. This won't work! Also you need to call at least 1 function from outside, the functions won't run by themselves. Look at this little example here: http://brugbart.com/autoit-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you never call your Hello() function. To execute a function you have to call it.

Try adding Hello() at the top of the file and it should work.